# How do I update customer store credit programmatically

Tags: magento, credits

I'm working with Magento ver. 1.9.1.1. and I need to update store credit balance for a customer. I know that it's possible to do it in Magento admin interface, but in my case I need to do an HTTP request to a server and actually do the same manipulations as we can do via Magento admin interface.

On the internet I found [a code](http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/useful-code-snippets) which allows to create a Credit Memo. Does I have to create a credit Memo to update customer store credit balance or it's not necessary?

Does someone has any idea how to do it?

I appreciate any answers. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
$balance = Mage::getModel('enterprise_customerbalance/balance')
                    ->setCustomer($customer)
                    ->setWebsiteId($websiteId)
                    ->setAmountDelta($anyNumber)
                    ->setComment($data['comment']);

$balance->save();
```

take more look at function customerSaveAfter() in observer of customerBalance module

Comment: Thank you very much. It works. Just setComment function does not want to work. I'll see why and will post here the fix.

Comment: I still can not make work "setComment" function. When I execute the code all works great, but I just do not have any comment for the action. Do you have any idea why? maybe it is not a good function...

Comment: I think for setComment to work you also need to declare who is updating the record which is not stated here. When I do this on the Admin side it lists the uid of who is updating plus the comment.

Comment: Thank you very much Greg. Your tip really helped me. I use code from [here](http://dineshinmca.blogspot.jp/2012/10/magento-how-to-login-to-magento-admin.html) to login to magento admin before update balance and after that comment is set properly. I hope this may be useful for someone else too.

Comment: Instead of `setComment` use `setUpdatedActionAdditionalInfo`

Answer (score 4):

This will work perfectly

```
$balance = Mage::getModel('enterprise_customerbalance/balance');
$balance->setCustomerId($customer_id)
        ->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId())
        ->loadByCustomer();

$current_balance = $balance->getAmount();
$comment = 'This is a comment that will appear in the credit update history';

// add store credit
$balance->setAmount($current_balance);
$balance->setAmountDelta($amount_to_be_added);
$balance->setUpdatedActionAdditionalInfo($comment);
$balance->setHistoryAction(1); // 1= updated
$balance->save();
```