# Fatal error: Call to a member function setCustomer() on boolean in

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

When I use the below code for updating store credit balance to customer, I am getting this error:

> Fatal Error: Call to a member function setCustomer() on boolean in

```
$balance = Mage::getModel('enterprise_customerbalance/balance')
                    ->setCustomer($customer)
                    ->setWebsiteId($websiteId)
                    ->setAmountDelta($anyNumber)
                    ->setComment($data['comment']);

$balance->save();
```

Comment: And also I am using credit memo extension.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the code `Mage::getModel('enterprise_customerbalance/balance')` returns `false`.

Please, verify if you have the `Enterprise_CustomerBalance_Model_Balance` class.

Maybe you are trying to use the code of Magento Enterprise Edition for Magento Community Edition.

If you watch the value of `$className` in the method `getModelInstance` of the `Mage_Core_Model_Config` class. It returns the 'Mage_Enterprise_Customerbalance_Model_Balance' value in Magento Community Edition. There is no such class and the function `Mage::getModel('enterprise_customerbalance/balance')` returns false.

You may try to check the edition with the code (it should work if the Magento Community version >= 1.7) -  `Mage::getEdition()`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am using magento 1.9 community edition. is their any other module so that I can use.

Comment: @KaushikDey There is no such module in the Core of Magento Community Edition. Maybe some of the extensions below has the functionality you need: Amasty - Store Credit, Magestore - Magento Store Credit extension, Mageworx - Magento Loyalty Booster extension v2.9.3

Answer (score 0):

Make sure this model class (or its parent) has a method named setCustomer()

Share model Code to get further advice. Normally class constructors don't return boolean.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I just found that code from here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17040183/how-do-i-update-customer-store-credit-programmatically). I am not sure which model you want to see ?

Answer (score 0):

after some code review here you are:

```
$balance = Mage::getModel('enterprise_customerbalance/balance')
            ->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
            ->setWebsiteId($websiteId)
            ->loadByCustomer();

$balance->setAmountDelta($anyNumber)
    ->setUpdatedActionAdditionalInfo($data['comment'])
    ->setHistoryAction(1)
    ->save();
```

Comment: I use your code but same result : Fatal error: Call to a member function setCustomerId() on boolean in...And I am using magehit storecredit.

Comment: What version of magento EE are you using?

Comment: I a using 1.9 magento CE

Comment: than you simply don't have enterprise_customerbalance. This module is not available in CE